# I have n list items. I need to get no of item which has class active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a slider which changes the active class on click of next and previous, I want the nth child each time which has class active.
e.g. in current scenario it should return 3

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> list item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> list item</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"> list item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> list item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> list item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> list item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> list item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function getCurrentItem() {
    var listItem = $(".my-list ul li");
    var items = [];
    for (i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
        items[i] = listItem;
        if($(items[i]).hasClass("active")){
            console.log("here: "+i);
        }
    }
}
 getCurrentItem();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be creating the array with the correct length?
eg/ var items = [listItem.length]

Comment: You want the `<li />` item or its position in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) can be used to the the index of the element. Note that `index()` will return zero-based index of the element. So, in current example, it'll return 2.

```
return $('.my-list li.active').index();
```

If the index need to be start from 1, add one to the zero-based index.

```
return $('.my-list li.active').index() + 1;
```

```js
console.log($('.my-list li.active').index() + 1);
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> list item 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> list item 2</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"> list item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> list item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> list item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> list item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> list item 7</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `index()`:

```
var currentActive = $('li.active').index() + 1; // 3, in this case
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getCurrentItem() {
    var listItem = $(".my-list ul li");
    for (i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
        if ($(listItem[i]).hasClass("active")) {
            console.log("here: " + i);
            return i + 1; //weve found it, lets return
            break;
        }
    }
    return " empty";
}
alert(getCurrentItem()); //should alert 3 in your case
```

Comment: No need of `break;` you can return the index from there